# Creating a computed column in Postgres throws generation expression is not immutable error

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

My column called check_out, check_in of type text has the format: "12:58" and I am converting to timestamp in order to make a subtraction and obtain the total hours.

I get the following error message in supabase: `Failed to run sql query: generation expression is not immutable`.

```
alter table attendance
add column totalhours text generated always as (
to_timestamp(check_out, 'HH24:MI') - to_timestamp(check_in, 'HH24:MI')
) stored;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't allow you to directly perform operations whilst altering the table and adding columns. In your case, the subtraction would take place between the timestamps only if it has something that doesn't change at the instance where the data is added, ie. immutable. To achieve that, you can create a custom function that converts the value and stores it; and then later, add it onto the table.

The function would go along the lines

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_total_hours(check_out text, check_in text)
RETURNS interval AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (to_timestamp(check_out, 'HH24:MI') - to_timestamp(check_in, 'HH24:MI'));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

and then, using this function, you can do what you intended

```sql
ALTER TABLE attendance
ADD COLUMN totalhours interval GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    calculate_total_hours(check_out, check_in)
) STORED;
```

Now, how does this avoid the error? Well, since you're defining the function as an immutable type, it will avert the inconsistency in results based on the input parameters that usually occur while dealing with timestamps.

Comment: amazing work, thank you for taking time to help, thanks friend

Comment: ofcourse! enjoy your day

Comment: If the above resolved you issue then kindly accept it. This helps future questioners with the same/similar issues and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.